# How to restore /sysroot on Fedora 20

Tags: fedora, lvm

I can't boot my Fedora 20 system as usual. Upon boot I get the message

```
Entering emergency mode. Exit the shell to continue.
```

journalctl reveals the following:

```
systemd[1]: Starting Switch Root...
systemd[1]: Not switching root: /sysroot does not seem to be an OS tree. /etc/os-release is missing.
systemctl[391]: Failed to issue method call: Invalid argument
systemd[1]: initrd-switch-root.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: Failed to start Switch Root.
systemd[1]: Startup finished in ...
```

I ran fsck on /dev/mapper/fedora-root, which appeared to direct a lot of stuff to /lost+found. It's now clean, apparently.

ls / (from emergency mode) gives:

```
bin dev dracut-state.sh etc init lib lib64 proc root run sbin shutdown sys sysroot tmp usr var
```

I can ls each of these directories, but they appear much smaller than usual and lack stuff I know was there. Is this a consequence of emergency mode or a corrupted file system?

My direct question is: how do I restore /sysroot and /etc/os-release? However, I'm worried that this isn't the only damage, and that when this is fixed more problems will be revealed, so my secondary question is: how do I detect and fix any further problems that might have been caused? I do not have a backup of these (I've just discovered that I'm stupidly only backing up /home, when I thought I was backing up everything).

Background to the problem: I dual boot Windows and Fedora 20 on separate hard disks. /dev/sda and /dev/sdb both contain NTFS partitions for Windows. /dev/sdc is and SSD for /boot and everything except /home; /home is on /dev/md127. Everything was working fine, I booted into Windows for the first time in quite a while to use some Windows software, then booted back into Linux and had this problem. I've done this many times before in the past, so not sure whether or not this is the cause of the issue.

/dev/sdc2 (where the OS resides) is an LVM partition.

Please tell me if I can be any more specific, if I can provide any more information that is relevant, or if there are any additional diagnostics I can run.

Thank you!

Comment: What is in `lost+found`?  Maybe `os-release`?

Comment: Good idea! The names are just numbers, but I have 22 files, #12 is a symlink to usr/bin, #13 is a symlink to usr/lib, #14 is a symlink to usr/lib64, and #15 is a symlink to usr/sbin. There are several directories, for example #1048577 which contains files cam1, cdrom and md0. #18 is the only file, size is 131161 (bytes?), timestamped Jul30, cat \#18 | less reveals the first line is x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu;VERSION=2, second line is S/usr/bin/mount and then it goes into a mix of weird characters and directories. Could that be os-release? Thank you!

Comment: I have Fedora 16 and 17 at hand; 16 doesn't have such a file.  17 (unusually) seems to need attention at the moment.  But as a guess, that does seem like the right thing.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work (same symptoms as before). Thanks anyway, though!